# Making AngularJS Web App Mobile Friendly

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS website that I want to make mobile friendly. The only way I could get it to function properly was to modify index.html viewport as follows:

If I did not set the initial scale small, portions of the webpage would not function on the phone.

However, making the initial scale small also makes it very tiny when the user first opens it - which is not helpful.

How do I go about making the web app mobile friendly? Everyone suggested viewport was the way to go, but I tried multiple configurations in addition to the above (the right hand menu pane would not display in many of them).

Thank you kindly

Comment: It did not allow me to use <> tags - I set viewport initial scale to .2 and shrink-to-fit to 'no' and width to device-width on content of viewport

Answer (score 0):

Turns out setting viewport meta tag worked fine - problem was I had a menu that was fixed on right side of the viewport. Needed to move everything to left and make sure it resized appropriately.